# What can I do about "Written Chinese"?

Tags: websites

Every time I go to the dictionary of Written Chinese, it stops working! How should I fix!? http://dictionary.writtenchinese.com/#sk=idiot&svt=pinyin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a technical question.

Answer (score 1):

It shows a server error (503), so you probably can't do anything about it, except using another dictionary.

Try one of these:

- [LINE Dict Chinese-English](https://dict.naver.com/linedict/zhendict/#/cnen/home)
- [MDBG Chinese Dictionary](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary)
- [Chinese Dictionary](https://dict.naver.com/linedict/zhendict/#/cnen/home)